# Sort only one column and no the others in a QTableView. Independent columns

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt you can have a QTableView to show the contents of a model like a table. In addition, you can implement sorting easily for example with a QSortFilterProxyModel. If you click on column B the rows of the table will be sorted according to the values of column B. In other words, the full rows are "moved".

However, I want to show data in a table where each column is "independent". And I want to be able to sort each column independently. If I click on column B I want to sort only the contents of column B and don't move the contents of the other columns.

How can it be implemented in Qt?

Example: 
I have 3 collections of values that I show them in a table:

```
collectionA  |   collectionB   | collectionC
     -4             10               13.5
     -7             4.5              56.2
     6                               23.0
                                     -11.4
```

Hence, if I click on column B I want to obtain:

```
collectionA  |   collectionB   | collectionC
     -4             4.5               13.5
     -7             10                56.2
     6                                23.0
                                     -11.4
```

Comment: From the description it appears that you don't really have data that's suited to a table.  Rather, you actually have three independent lists that should be displayed using three [QListViews](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html).

Comment: @G.M. Well, it is true, but visually it is more appealing to show the data in one table (like excel) than to have X different QListViews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the fact that the user experience would be weird if you implement such a behaviour (high risk that the fact that collection A, collectionB do not re-arrange when sorting collectionC is reported as a bug); here is a solution to the problem :

do not set the tableView sortable but connect a customSort function to rearrange your data model upon click on horizontalHeader. Of course this solution modify the data model and not only the view, so if you have multiple views for this data model it may not suit your need :

File mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QHeaderView>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

model = std::make_unique<QStandardItemModel>(5,2);

for( int r=0; r<5; r++ )
  for( int c=0; c<2; c++)
  {
    QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem( QString("Row:%0, Column:%1").arg(r).arg(c) );

    model->setItem(r, c, item);
  }

model->setHorizontalHeaderItem( 0, new QStandardItem( "Foo" ) );
model->setHorizontalHeaderItem( 1, new QStandardItem( "Bar-Baz" ) );


   ui->tableView->setModel(model.get());

   connect(   ui->tableView->horizontalHeader(), &QHeaderView::sectionClicked , this , &MainWindow::customSort);

}

void MainWindow::customSort( int columnIndex)
{
auto itemOfColumn = model->takeColumn(columnIndex);

//reverse the list, or whatever sorting you might want...
for(int k = 0; k < (itemOfColumn.size()/2); k++) itemOfColumn.swap(k,itemOfColumn.size()-(1+k));

model->insertColumn(columnIndex,itemOfColumn);

model->setHorizontalHeaderItem( 0, new QStandardItem( "Foo" ) );
model->setHorizontalHeaderItem( 1, new QStandardItem( "Bar-Baz" ) );

}
```

File mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <memory>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();

private:

void customSort(int);

Ui::MainWindow *ui;

std::unique_ptr<QStandardItemModel> model;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```